# Doubt with current across several resistors (serie) and Resistor Power Rating

Tags: current, resistors, series, power-consumption

I have read that the current that flows across a circuit of several elements connected in serie is always the same but, as far as I understand, resistors consume current and disipates it in form of heat, am I right?

If the above is correct, if you have 3 resistors (R1, R2, R3) connected in serie, the current through R3 will be less than the one through R1, right? If so, is the afirmation *"the current flowing in a serie circuit is always the same"* false?

Is the above applicable for both AC and DC circuits?

Does the same occur for inductances?

Comment: three resistors in series is similar to three garden hoses connected together .... the volume of water flowing through any point along the hoses is the same

Answer (score 2):

> I have read that the current that flows across a circuit

Current flows *through* things.  Voltage exists *across* things.

> of several elements connected in serie[s] is always the same

Yes.

> but, as far as I understand, resistors consume current and disipates it in form of heat, am I right?

No.  Resistors don't "consume" current.  The rest of your question makes no sense since it is based on this false premise.

You really need to go back to the very basics of electronics, starting with voltage and current.